# Need simple code: Get Glassfish InitialContext & lookup ConnectionFactory

Tags: glassfish, jms, jndi

My glassfish4 server runs on localhost.

My java client is a simple GUI run from Eclipse.

My glassfish4 admin console assures me I have a Resources/JMS Resources/Connection Factories/jms/goConnectionFactory properly configured.

So I though it would be trivial for the client to get an InitialContext from glassfish and use it to lookup "jms/goConnectionFactory.  Not true,

And after reading answered questions (all too wrapped up in other special issues to be helpful) I still can't connect.

Can anyone tell me the properties I need to load to make this work?

```
Properties prop = new Properties:
   prop.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
        "com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory");
   prop.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,
        "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
   prop.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort","3700");
   prop.etProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost","localhost");
   System.out.printlin (jndiContext.getClass().getName();

InitialContext jndiContext = new InitialContext (props);

ConnectionFactory = 
    (ConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup("jms/goConnectionFactory");
```

The  1st printlin() returns this to the console "javax.naming.InitialContext".

But a try/catch block (not shown) around the lookup() catches a NullPointerException

And I don't know how to tell if my InitialContext object is a valid one from my glassfish4 server, or I'm using it incorrectly.

Anyway ... a glassfish server, and a java GUI client (run from Eclipse), both running on the same machine seems a pretty generic arrangement.  So I'm sure it would help all newbees to JMS to have just one trivial snipt of code that proves it works -- without having to spend a week hunting to no avail.

Note:  I also tried

```
factory =
      (ConnectionFactory)
        PortableRemoteObject.narrow(
          jndiContext.lookup("jms/goConnectionFactory"),
          ConnectionFactory.class
       );
```

But I'm pretty sure I won't need that till I try to get my local client to talk to my glassfish4 running on a virtual server elsewhere.

And I used "localhost:8080", instead of just "localhost", in prop above.  Same result.  I get some kind of InitialContext Object.  But it won't retrieve a ConnectionFactory.

Can anyone offer any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
...
    System.out.printlin (jndiContext.getClass().getName();

    InitialContext jndiContext = new InitialContext (props);
...
```

Isn't the first line the cause of your null pointer? The jndiContext is not yet initialized at that point.